# SQL Agent "Use 32 BIT Runtime" Option missing in Execution options

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, 32bit-64bit, sql-job

I am trying to run an SSIS job which loads data from an Excel. I need to run the package in 32bit but that option is missing when I try to create the job.

[image: 32-Bit option Missing]

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: In the SQL Server installation program, if you check either Client Tools or SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) the installation program will automatically also install 32-bit Integration services. If you don't check either one, the 32-bit version of Integration Services will not be installed.

Answer (score 1):

This was happening to me as well, with Visual Studio 2019 on SQL Server 2019. I already had SSDT and Client Tools installed.

On the server, the version of Management Studio was a little older (v18.6) than the one on my desktop, which was working. I updated the server Mgmt. Studio to v18.6, 15.0.18338.0 and I could find the 32 bit check box.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's due to SSMS versions, but on my job, the location has changed tabs. FYI, I'm using SSMS version 18.12.1

[image]